# Azure - Running an http server on an VM

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a VM on Windows Azure with Ubuntu 12.04 running on it.

I have two end-points
**End-point1**
public port: 50348
private port: 22

**End-point2**
public port: 81
private port: 81

Now, I have a simple python HTTP server running on the Virtual Machine, which is listening on port 81.

When I try to connect to localhost:81 from within the Virtual machine, I am able to connect, so I know that the server is up and running.

Say, the DNS name assigned to my VM be `blah-blah.cloudapp.net`

But, when I try to connect to `http://blah-blah.cloudapp.net:81` from somewhere outside, I always get a Server Not Found error.

So, how can I connect to my server?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that port 81 is blocked by firewall in Ubuntu?

Comment: No, that's not the problem. Till now I was trying with firefox. I tried opening the site with IE and it works. It's very weird. Not able to understand why firefox is not able to connect.

Comment: Sounds weird! Have you already read this related article? https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/how-to-load-balance-virtual-machines/